# HTMLParser and BeautifulSoup not decoding HTML entities correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-entities, html-parser

I am trying to decode `HTML entities` from a section of `HTML` source code with both `HTMLParser` and `BeautifulSoup`

However neither seems to work completely. Namely they don't decode slashes.

My Python version is `2.7.11` with `BeautifulSoup` version `3.2.1`

```
print 'ORIGINAL STRING: %s \n' % original_url_string

#clean up
try:
    # Python 2.6-2.7
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    from html.parser import HTMLParser

h = HTMLParser()
url_string = h.unescape(original_url_string)

print 'CLEANED WITH html.parser: %s \n' % url_string

decoded = BeautifulSoup( original_url_string,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

print 'CLEANED WITH BeautifulSoup: %s \n' % decoded.contents
```

Gives me an output like:

```
ORIGINAL STRING: api.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F277561480&#038;show_artwork=true&#038;maxwidth=1050&#038;maxheight=1000 

CLEANED WITH html.parser: api.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F277561480&show_artwork=true&maxwidth=1050&maxheight=1000 

CLEANED WITH BeautifulSoup: [u'api.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F277561480&show_artwork=true&maxwidth=1050&maxheight=1000']
```

What am I missing here?

Should I try to decode the entire `HTML` page before pulling out the urls?

Is there a better way to do this with Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to decode the slashes from the url or the url's html?

If you re trying to decode the slashes, they are not [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), but percent-encoded characters.

`urllib` has the method you need:

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote(original_url_string)
>>> 'api.soundcloud.com/tracks/277561480&#038;show_artwork=true&#038;maxwidth=1050&#038;maxheight=1000'
```

If you want to decode the html, you first have to `get` it with a package like `requests` or `urllib`